# Using the name.com API

Tags: php

I've been trying to work with name.com's API, and I just can't seem to get it to work.

Below you will see everything I have used in trying to just simply get the account username...

```
$api = new NameComApi();
$api->username('myusername');
$api->apiToken('mytoken');
```

And then of course the simple usage example they provide to get account details:

```
if($nameAccount = $api->get_account()){
   echo $nameAccount->username;
   }else {
    echo 'Seems to be an error';
}
```

The "Seems to be an error" is never returned either. So that tells me at least part of it is working.

I've tried returning both an array

```
$nameAccount['username'];
```

and an object... as you see currently in my code

```
$nameAccount->username;
```

Just doesn't return anything at all. 
Any guidance would be well appreciated.

Comment: Do you get any output at all from the php? Try placing an `echo` right at the beginning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve my own issue. Was a simple logic error in the name.com class file.